# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host on IIS on Remote Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient

> *Exception:
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
>
> ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
>
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---*

Getting this error for an ASP .NET Core 6 MVC Project.

Quick Background: I initially had this project hosted on IIS on a remote machine and got it working last week.

This has the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ISampleClient, SampleClient>()
// Temporary for server
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
{
    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
    return clientHandler;
});
```

Note the **ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback**.

And the SampleClient class is:

```
public SampleClient(HttpClient httpClient, IMapper mapper, IConfiguration config)
{
    _httpClient = httpClient;
    _mapper = mapper;
    _config = config;
    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_config["BaseAddress"]);
}

public async Task<Sample> GetSampleAsync()
{
    return await GetAsync<Sample>("api/Sample");
}

private async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url)
{
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "3600");
    return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<T>(url);
}
```

The Base address in config is just the domain it is hosted in IIS defined in bindings. As mentioned, I set ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback as we want to bypass SSL for now. This is just for testing and to demo internally.

The API Controller is in this same project. When hosted, the API can be reached and returns data.

I have published this last week, but with bindings to localhost, that worked. However, our infra team wanted to expose this to other computers in the network, they made changes to the bindings (of which are mostly the same except the hostname). Apparently causing the issue, but I'm not 100% convinced.

I have tried multiple suggestions relating to the error message shown, in editing the Security Protocol, even though there was a lack of understanding, I have added the code in the `SampleClient` class.

I would like to add, on my local machine, it works with no problems, but I have the localhost binding. I think it's because of the custom domain in IIS?

I'm hoping to get more suggestions to get this fixed.

EDIT: Additional Information, when publishing using the hostname https://svdb01.sample.com.au, it fails, but when the binding is https://localhost, it works!

Comment: SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 were made obsolete around 7 years ago and gave industry 5 years to change to TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  Two years ago Microsoft made a security push disabling the obsolete versions on servers.  Also most servers now require HTTPS (which uses TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3)  For code to work you would need to use HTTP (not HTTPS) and enable HTTP on server.

Comment: To make sure I understand you correct @jdweng, you mean I need to add a separate binding using http?

Comment: You said "we want to bypass SSL for now".  Which means you want to use HTTP instead of HTTPS.  All I'm saying is most servers require HTTPS as the default setting.

Comment: You certificate may be expired or not compatible with TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  TLS the server sends a certificate block with a list of certificate names.  The client then looks up the certificate names in the stores to see if a matching name exists.  You are using a particular certificate that must be loaded on the server.  Also encryption mode has to be compatible with version of Windows.  Starting with Net 4.7.2 TLS defaults to operating system instead of Net Library.  So the operating system must be capable of the encryption mode.  Check certificate with Notepad to see encryption mode.