# Error in calling REST service after publishing ASP.NET Core project on IIS

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-core, restsharp

I have to call some services from a origin in ASP.NET Core project. Services are working correctly when I trace code.

After I publish, all of the services are working correctly, except this one service that did work correctly in debugging mode.

Here is my code :

```
var rqs = new RestRequest("", Method.Get)
{
    Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3).TotalMilliseconds
};

rqs.AddParameter("action", "getCurrentActivations");
rqs.AddParameter("dt", $"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}");

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

var res = await _cli.ExecuteAsync(rqs);

if (res.Content is null)
    throw new BusinessException($"null content in origin response!\n({res.ErrorException?.Message})\n({res.ErrorException?.InnerException?.Message})", 500);

var activations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CurrentActivationsResultDto>(res.Content);

return activations;
```

Here is logged exception message :

> null content in origin response! (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.) (Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..)

Note: when I call this service from Postman, it works correctly

Comment: Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72770304/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host-on-iis-on-remote-s) to see if it will help you.